# Compare two databases and get the differences

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

I want to between two databases and get the differences:

1. **columns**: in the first table the column `name` is `varchar2(12)`, in the  second table the column `name` is `varchar2(20)`. Or I have an
   additional column in the first table.
2. **data**: I have to compare data between the same tables in different databases

I am aware of [`DBMS_COMPARISON`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_comparison.htm#ARPLS868), but need to do this on Oracle 10g.

---

Added after the [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/130905/1192) by thatjeffsmith:

I know that SQL Developer can do that, but I have to develop a J2EE application which does that.

Answer (score 4):

For item #1, you can use the Database Diff feature in SQL Developer - and yes, it should work on Oracle 10g.

[image]

This is a free feature in a no-cost tool provided by Oracle Corp.